# AnyOpenId site for OpenId authentication stopped working

Tags: facebook, twitter, openid

Does anyone know if http://anyopenid has stopped existing or has be compromised as I get 404 errors and cannot use the Facebook OpenId Url i.e. http://facebook.anyopenid.com/. Is there an alternative or will I need to use the OAuth to authenticate users on my application via their Facebook, Twitter accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I was emailing with one of the developers, and he told me that it has been sun-setted due to poor uptake and high maintenance costs.  Too bad; it was a great service.  :-(  We have moved to using OAuth on our site as a result.